# prolog avoiding duplicate predicates

Tags: database, prolog, duplicates

I was wondering whether it is possible to test whether a predicate already exists (with the same information) to then avoid the user being able to input the same information again.

I have already managed to do it for a single predicate:

```
:- dynamic(test/2).

test(a,b).

top(X,Y) :-
    (test(X,Y),
     write('Yes'),!
    ;write('No'),!
    ).
```

This version works just fine, returning 'Yes' if the information already exists and 'No' if it doesn't.

I was wondering whether it would be possible to do this for multiple prediactes, not just for 'test/2';
I have tried to replace the predicate 'test' with a variable Pred but unfortunately I get a syntax error when I try to compile it.
Here is my attempt:

```
 main(Pred,X,Y) :-
      (Pred(X,Y),
       write('Yes'),!
      ;write('No'),!
      ).
```

Is it even possible to do something like this and if it is how would it be possible?

Btw I am using GNU Prolog if it helps.

Thank you very much for your help :D !!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `-->` in the if-then-else?

Comment: You're not checking for existence of a predicate. You're checking to see if certain query or facts are true, correct? It's one thing to check if `Pred` exists at all as a predicate, but another to determine if `test(X, Y)` (or `call(Pred, X, Y)`) succeeds for a specific `X` and/or `Y`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [call/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=call/2), to call a dynamic goal with arguments, evaluated at runtime. In your case, it would be `call(Pred,X,Y)`:

```
main(Pred,X,Y) :-
    (
        call(Pred,X,Y),
        write('Yes'),!
    )
    ;
    (
        write('No'),!
    ).
```

Do note that `Pred/2` must resolve to an actual predicate at runtime, and you will need to build a different rule for each number of arguments.

@Tomas-By's answer, using [(=..)/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D..)/2) lets you create a single rule, with a list of args, but with the same caveats regarding predicates existing, albeit with an extra line:

```
main(Pred,L) :- % where L is a list of args [X,Y|...]
    Term =.. [Pred | L],
    (
        Term,
        write('Yes'),!
    )
    ;
    (
        write('No'),!
    ).
```

And, as pointed out in the comments by @lurker, in either instance, using [(->)/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(-%3E)/2):

```
(call(Pred,X,Y) -> write('Yes') ; write('No'))
```

or

```
(Term -> write('Yes') ; write('No'))
```

may be preferable as the destruction of choice points is limited to the if->then;else structure.

Comment: I would also use the `p1 -> p2 ; p3` construct, which behaves as `p1, ! ; p2`, rather than use `(p1, !) ; (p2, !)`.

Comment: `clause/2` and `current_predicate/1` can also be used to poke around at what's already defined.

Answer (score 1):

There is an operator =.. for constructing terms, as in:

```
Term =.. [Op,V1,V2]
```

not sure if that is in Gnu Prolog.

Using Sicstus:

```
xxx(1,2).

check(Pred,X,Y) :-
  Term =.. [Pred,X,Y],
  ( Term ->
    write('Yes')
  ; write('No') ).
```

and after loading the file:

```
| ?- check(xxx,1,2).
Yes
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I have included the information you have used (with attribution!) in my answer, to make the accepted answer more complete. If you would prefer, I can remove it.